# Jooq entity mapping

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have following schema:

Projects (ID, NAME)
Projects_Users (PROJECT_ID, USERS_ID)
Users (NAME, ID)

Entity are as follows

```
public class Projects {

    private String name;
    private long id;
    private List<User> users;

    public Projects() {
    }
}


public class User {

    private String name;
    private Long id;
}
```

so clearly one-to-many. Projects can have multiple users.

Now my goal is to write jooq query where I can fetch project objects already with corresponding users.

```
.select(PROJECT.NAME, PROJECT.ID, USERS)
.from(PROJECT)
.join(USERS_PROJECT).on(USERS_PROJECT.PROJECT_ID=PROJECT.ID)
.join(USERS).on(USERS.ID=USERS_PROJECT.USER_ID)
.fetchInto(Project.class);
```

but the query would resturn thousends results when expecting ~15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing two things:

#### Run a jOOQ query:

```
.select(PROJECT.NAME, PROJECT.ID, USERS)
.from(PROJECT)
.join(USERS_PROJECT).on(USERS_PROJECT.PROJECT_ID.eq(PROJECT.ID))
.join(USERS).on(USERS.ID.eq(USERS_PROJECT.USER_ID))
.fetch();
```

This is straightforward. jOOQ transforms the above expression to a SQL string, sends it to JDBC, receives the result set and provides you with a jOOQ [`Result`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html). Obviously, the result is denormalised (because you wrote joins), and thus you have many rows (about as many as there are rows in the `USERS_PROJECT` table).

#### Map the `Result` to your POJO

Now, this is what's confusing you. You called `fetchInto(Project.class)`, which is just syntax sugar for calling [`fetch()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetch--).[`into(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#into-java.lang.Class-). These are two separate steps, and in particular, the `into(Class)` step has no knowledge of your query nor of your intent. Thus, it doesn't "know" that you're expecting ~15 unique projects, and a nested collection of users.

But there are ways to map things more explicitly. E.g. by using [`intoGroups(Class, Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#intoGroups-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-). This may not return nested types as you designed them, but something like a

```
Map<Person, List<User>> map = query.fetch().intoGroups(Person.class, User.class);
```

You can take it from there, manually. Or, you can write a [`RecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordMapper.html) and use that:

```
List<Person> list = query.fetch().map(record -> new Person(...));
```

Or, you could use any of the [recommended third party mappers](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/), e.g.:

- http://modelmapper.org
- http://simpleflatmapper.org

Comment: what if the user.class and person.class are not entity classes(Tables). I want a customized response. is there any way we can achieve it?

Comment: @GauravRatnawat: The best way to get a customised response is to ask a customised question!